# JQueryMobile addEventListener causing TypeError: undefined - yet still executing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, resize, addeventlistener, iscroll4

I'm using a very standard "one-page" model for JQueryMobile development like:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div id="mycontent" data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

When I click a link to navigate from page1 to page2, I'm appending content to $("#mycontent") that contains images that do not always have specified width/height, then I'm applying iScroll-4 so that I can scroll/zoom the content - in some cases I need to zoom it as soon as it is loaded so it fits nicely on a mobile screen (generally 600px wide to start).  The problem is, once the images load, the formatting falls apart, particularly since I need to reposition the element, as CSS zoom likes to center the zoomed item, not align to top/left corner.

That was probably a long explanation for a simple problem (maybe there is a better way to do the above?), but here is my real problem:  I'm trying to add an event listener for the load event on the div, so that I can check to see if I need to reposition the div once all the images are loaded:

```
$("#mycontent").addEventListener('load', doSomething(), false);

function doSomething(){  alert("something");  }
```

The crazy thing is, doSomething() **DOES** get fired, but then Safari throws the following error and crashes JQuery:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$("#mycontent").addEventListener('load', doSomething(),
>   false)')

The element is present in the DOM, and it's definitely loaded at the time the event listener is added - and I guess this is made clear by the fact that it fires.  JQM applies some styles to the element as it is transitioning, but I don't see how that would affect it.

Any help would be appreciated, as I've been banging my head against this for a while and am about to write some very ugly looping hacks to check for size changes :/

Comment: I should add that I'm calling the code to addEventListener within the pageshow event, but I've also tried it in the pagebeforeshow event.  Any of the earlier events in the sequence result in a different error and the function does NOT get fired.  I believe that error was due to the element not existing yet.  It must be temporarily removed in the transition...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible issues. The second parameter of addEventListener should be a function, not a function call: `element.addEventListener("load", doSomething, false);`. In your code the `doSomething()` is executed whatever the event name is.

Also, `$('#mycontent')` returns an array of elements which I think causes your TypeError, so you might want to use:

```
var mycontent = document.getElementById('mycontent');
mycontent.addEventListener("load", doSomething, false);
```

JQuery also has [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which might work, if you listen to each image's load event and adjust your layout:

```
$('#mycontent img').load(doSomething);
```

This will fire once for each image, so you might want to keep a count if you know the number of images, or else create / reset a timeout on each load, and after the timeout call doSomething.

Comment: Thanks Oiva, I'll give these a shot and follow up in the morning.  JQuery load() was not working for me, but the other two may.  As for the last part, I can definitely get a count of image tags, so this could work.  I'm hoping binding the load event to 50+ images on a mobile device won't be too much to handle.  I guess we'll see!

Comment: When I tried changing to doSomething as the callback, it simply did nothing.  After some research, many here on Stack say load only works on the window object and images, where it's sketchy at best.  In other words, no divs.  I also read through JQuery's site a bit more and they say calling load on an image is dicey at best.  I'll mark this as the answer, since it did help me understand that $("#mycontent") was returning an array, which was causing the error that was part of my question.  Moving past the error led me to see an unrelated solution which helped me bypass this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is you're using JQuery and try to add event bypassing the JQuery API. You mustn't use the addEventListener method. Use the `$('#mycontent').load(handler)` instead, where handler is a function accepting on argument. e.g. `$('#mycontent').load(function (e) {alert ("loaded")})`